When do I pay the cost in Ulalek's triggered ability?
I’m looking at the ability of one of the upcoming Eldrazi releases, and was wondering when payment happens and when the ability goes on the stack.
Ulalek, Fused Atrocity has the ability

Whenever you cast an Eldrazi spell, you may pay {C}{C}. If you do, copy all spells you control, then copy all other activated and triggered abilities you control. You may choose new targets for the copies. (Mana abilities can’t be copied.)

When I cast an Eldrazi, does the trigger go on the stack and then I pay, and if I do does it create a new trigger without the payment part saying to copy, or do I pay before it goes on the stack at all?
Part of the confusion is with the period after the payment, I know having a period or not can change things and this is why I’m asking.

This is a single triggered ability. A triggered ability is indicated by the word "when", "whenever", or "at". This ability only has one of those, once, so there's no part that creates another triggered ability.
You follow all of the instructions in the ability as the ability resolves. First, you decide whether to pay the cost, and you can activate mana abilities to do so. Then, if you do pay it, you follow the rest of the instructions, otherwise nothing happens.

I know having a period or not can change things

This is not the case. It generally doesn't matter whether an ability is one sentence or multiple sentences.

So the ability would go to stack, the resolve all at once?

Yes, that is always how all activated and triggered abilities work. The only exception is if the ability creates another triggered ability during its resolution. That only happens if it uses the specific wording for a triggered ability in the middle of the ability, and this one does not do that.

@Littleinhuman To be clear, when Ulalek's triggered ability resolves (if you paid 2 colorless), it will put a copy of all your other spells, activated and triggered abilities on the stack. When you put them on the stack, you make any choices about targets, etc., but then the stack will unwind as normal, with each player getting priority before each subsequent item resolves.

So if you cast two Eldrazi, you have the option of paying CCCCCC to put three copies of everything onto the stack?

Actually, if you cast a second Eldrazi spell in response to this triggered ability, you can pay CC any number of times to copy everything else on the stack that many times. This works because each time you copy everything, that includes the first instance of this ability, which you can then use to copy everything again.

@murgatroid99 "This works because each time you copy everything, that includes the first instance of this ability" — No, the ability only copies other abilities, not itself.

I wasn't just talking about the general behavior, I was responding to Acccumulation's comment, and specifically addressing the scenario of casting a second Eldrazi spell while one instance of this ability is already on the stack. If you do that, then the ability will trigger again in response to the second Eldrazi spell. When the second ability resolves, it will copy everything else on the stack, including the first instance of the ability. Then when that copy of the first instance of the ability resolves, it will again copy that instance, which can repeat indefinitely.
